# How to send Array of objects through json body in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*

I am trying to post this HTTP request by using this function

```
Future addOfferToCart(
      List<String> cartList,
      var merchant_id,
      var storeId,
      var user_id,
      var token,
      ) async {
    String url =
        "My API";
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "cart": [],
        "merchant_id": merchant_id,
        "store_id": storeId,
        "user_id": user_id
      }),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
    );
    var jData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(jData);
    return jData;
  }
```

///////////////////////////////END////////////////////////////////

For adding multiple items in cart I create an array of objects.
The variable `$cartList` has value of

```
[
    {
        "masterproductid": 0,
        "merchantlist_id": 0,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "masterproductid": 19265,
        "merchantlist_id": 306,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "masterproductid": 19265,
        "merchantlist_id": 306,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "masterproductid": 19790,
        "merchantlist_id": 306,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "masterproductid": 553,
        "merchantlist_id": 306,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "masterproductid": 552,
        "merchantlist_id": 306,
        "offer_id": 306,
        "offer_price": 69,
        "qty": "1"
    }
]
```

///////////////////////////////END////////////////////////////////

And For adding single item in cart I use this function

```
Future addOfferToCart(var masterProduct_id,
      var merchantlist_id,
      var offer_id,
      var offer_price,
      var qty,
      var merchant_id,
      var storeId,
      var user_id,
      var token,
  ) async {
    String url =
        "My API";
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "cart": [
          {
            "masterproductid": masterProduct_id,
            "merchantlist_id": merchantlist_id,
            "offer_id": offer_id,
            "offer_price": offer_price,
            "qty": qty
          }
        ],
        "merchant_id": merchant_id,
        "store_id": storeId,
        "user_id": user_id
      }),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
    );
    var jData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(jData);
    return jData;
  }
```

///////////////////////////////END////////////////////////////////

Comment: you just have to create a `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala it says `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: then you can create POJO class of that particular object and make a list of that particular POJO class